# No instance for (Fractional ((Numerator, Denominator) -> Fraction a0 b0))

Tags: haskell

I'm fairly new to Haskell and I seem to be stuck at one error in my code. I keep running into this error when I'm trying to override recip from fractional. My code is as follows:

```
type Numerator = Int
type Denominator = Int
data Fraction a b = Fraction (Numerator,Denominator)  deriving (Show, Eq)
instance (Fractional a, Fractional b) => Fractional (Fraction a b) where
    recip (Fraction(a,b)) =
        Fraction(b,a)
```

Is the problem due to the Numerator and Denominator are of type Int? I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I have basic arithmetic operations that are in working order.

Comment: There's no good reason to use type synonyms for the numerator and denominator. There's also no good reason to pair them. `data Fraction = Fraction Int Int` is a bit better. But integer overflow makes a mess of fractions, so you should consider `data Fraction = Fraction Integer Integer`.  Better still, `data Fraction = Fraction Integer Natural`, but I'm not sure if `Natural` made it to GHC 7.10 and it's definitely not in earlier versions. By the way, don't forget to deal with division by zero.

Comment: So the only reason I used the type synonyms was just force of habit, but that being said, I shall change it to Integer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't using the `a` or `b` in your `Fraction` data type, maybe you should just go with

```
data Fraction = Fraction (Numerator, Denominator)

instance Fractional Fraction where
    recip (Fraction (a, b)) = Fraction (b, a)
```

But this also requires a `Num` instance:

```
instance Num Fraction where
    ...
```

---

Basically, the reason for this error is because you specify that `a` and `b` must be fractional, but since that `a` and `b` aren't used in the constructor for `Fraction` the compiler has an arbitrary choice of which one to use.  It could do `Fractional (Fraction Float Double)`, or `Fractional (Fraction Double Float)`, or `Fractional (Fraction (Fraction Double Double) Float)`, so you see an error.

Comment: However, I am using a b within my code, it's just not at the part that is causing some errors. I use them in the Num functions such as addition and subtraction.

Comment: I would recommend looking at the implementation in `Data.Ratio` for ideas on how to structure your `Fraction` type.  My point is that your `a` and `b` type arguments to `Fraction` are phantom types, they aren't used by the only constructor for that type.  It'd be like if I wrote `data Foo a b c = Bar`.  The type variables aren't used in the data constructor `Bar`, only in the type constructor `Foo`, so type checking is more ambiguous

Comment: Okay, so reading into it, I tried working with your solution a little bit and seem to be running into the same issue when trying to recip. Would this be error on my end for writing out the Num instance?